# How do I run a specific Dart _test file with pub run test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dart

I have a bunch of files in my test_dir and the problem is that they must be run separately, because one of them is testing the code that can only be run in the browser and the other is testing code that can only be run in the backend.

Now, I know there's a `-n` argument to `pub run test` for specifying test name, but how do I run a specific file? It's not very clear from the documentation and I wasn't able to successfully accomplish that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add the directory or concrete file name

```
pub run test test/some_dir/some_file_test.dart
```

If you want to run certain tests only on console or only in the browser you can configure this per test or per file or alternatively in a project config file.

> Some test files only make sense to run on particular platforms. They may use `dart:html` or `dart:io`, they might test Windows' particular filesystem behavior, or they might use a feature that's only available in Chrome. The `@TestOn` annotation makes it easy to declare exactly which platforms a test file should run on. Just put it at the top of your file, before any library or import declarations:

```
@TestOn("vm") // or @TestOn("browser")

import "dart:io";

import "package:test/test.dart";

void main() {
  // ...
}
```

When you run all tests like

```
pub run test -pchrome -pfirefox -pie
```

Then this test will not be run because `-pvm` was not included.

This allows fine-grained configuration like

> For example, if you wanted to run a test on every browser but Chrome, you would write `@TestOn("browser && !chrome")`.

The test package has a great [README](https://github.com/dart-lang/test) for all other configuration options.

Answer (score 1):

If you have separated tests into separate files, say `browser_test.dart` and `vm_test.dart`, then it's simply:

```
pub run test test/browser_test.dart
pub run test test/vm_test.dart
```

See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test#running-tests